# Get relationships and nodes between two nodes

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

Given the following data set in Neo4j:

```
(A)-flows->(B)-flows->(C)-flows->(D)-flows->(Z)
(A)-flows->(E)-flows->(F)-flows->(Z)
(A)-flows->(G)-flows->(Z)
```

How can I return the subgraph (nodes B, C, D, E, F, G their relationships between each other and the relationships to A and Z) with a Cypher query when only A and Z is known.

Pseudo code:

```
Match(a)-[rels*](nodes*)-(z)
where a.Id = '123' and z.Id = '456'
return a,rels,nodes,z
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the `(A)->...->(Z)` subgraph to a [named path](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/match/#named-paths) then use the [`nodes`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-nodes) and [`relationships`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-relationships) functions to extract a list of nodes and relationships:

```
MATCH p=(a {Id: '123'})-[:flows*]->(z {Id: '456'})
RETURN a, nodes(p), relationships(p), z
```

As pointed out in the comments, `nodes(p)` also returns `a` and `z`. If you do not want those nodes to be returned, omit the first and last elements of the list. Thanks to Bruno Peres and cybersam for their inputs.

```
MATCH p=(a {Id: '123'})-[:flows*]->(z {Id: '456'})
RETURN a, nodes(p)[1..-1], relationships(p), z
```

**Remark #1.** It is also possible to [`UNWIND`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/) these lists to their content process one-by-one.

**Remark #2.** Depending on the driver your using, you can simply return `p` and process it in the client's code. For example, the Java driver allows use to return a [`Path`](http://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/types/Path.html) object that has `nodes()` and `relationships()` methods returning `Iterable`s.

Comment: Seems that the node `a` is being returned twice. For the `a` variable and on the `nodes(p)` call. The same for `z` node.

Comment: `x[1..size(x)-1]` can be written more succinctly as `x[1..-1]`.

Comment: Wow, that's new for me. Thanks!